# Going in circles trying to configure SSL VPN for Sonicwall TZ105

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

I'll preface this question by saying that I have made an effort to research this and I have been learning more about networking etc. as I broaden my IT experience, but VPN configuration still has gray areas for me.  Anyway...

We are a small office that has a 2-line bonded ADSL connection with our ISP (static IP).  The modem is bridged to our Sonicwall TZ 105 hardware firewall.  Off and on I have been trying to figure out how to set up a VPN connection so my boss can access our server remotely.  I don't have access to his network hardware (it's going to be just a standard modem from AT&T or Comcast or whoever).  What I can do is have him bring in his laptop and install the NetExtender client which should allow him to connect with SSL VPN.

We are all on PCs with Windows 7 Pro, also running AVG 2012 with Windows Firewall turned off (not sure if the software firewalls matter here).

### What I Did

I Tried to configure the SSL VPN using [this video](http://youtu.be/qPv-tz-zN6A), pretty much everything I did mimics what this guy does.

User setup:

1. I set up a user for him (bobdole) and a password.
2. I made user bobdole a member of the SSLVPN group and Trusted Users group for good measure, as instructed in the video.  For VPN Access tab I put LAN Subnets.

Server setup:

1. Enabled WAN SSL VPN on port 443 using AES 256 SHA1
2. Set client address range outside of normal DHCP range (assigned by the Sonicwall either way I think) 192.168.168.187-192
3. Set DNS server 1 and 2 to the same ones we use normally, they point to our ISP DNS servers.  Left DNS Domain blank.  Left UserDomain as "LocalDomain".  No WINS server.
4. Set up one client route: Lan Primary Subnet (as instructed in the video) which populates as 192.168.168.0/255.255.255.0.  This is the only client route.

### The Problem and Questions

I installed NetExtender on my workstation, which is inside the LAN that a remote user would be trying to connect to.  Should I try from outside the network?  I know that will be the application in the end but can I not test accessibility from inside the network?

I cannot connect with NetExtender.  No matter what I put in I get:

> "Error: The server is not reachable.  The server may be down or your
>   internet settings may be down."

The NetExtender login page looks like this after I enter in my information:

- Server: 111.11.11.111:443
- Username: bobdole
- Password: ********
- Domain: LocalDomain

I click "Connect" and the window says "Verifying User" for a few seconds before giving me the error.  I don't know where I screwed up or did not put something in correctly, or if it's just the fact that I can't do this from inside the network.

The Server IP I'm using is our public IP, which is a static IP.  The username is the one I set up in the Sonicwall, with the password.  Should I be entering in something else for the Server IP?  Leave port number off?  Any help or clarifying questions are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that trying to connect while inside the LAN is likely not going to work. There are relatively few of these multi-purpose prosumer appliances that support hairpin NAT, which is required for this to work.

So - just head to your local coffee shop, or tether to your phone and then try to VPN in.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  Thank you for the answer.  Does everything else seem ok?  I'll see if I can get a laptop with NE out or maybe even try from home.

Comment: If you have the Wireless TZ105 W model, you can connect via wireless and access your VPN. By default, the WLAN not have access to the LAN which avoids the NAT problem. SonicPoints may work as well. I believe the default configuration also keeps the WLAN separated.